# Total Sum based on specific Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I ran a query that gave me a date range between 05/04/20 and 08/24/20

Please see the sample Code:

**

```
SELECT SM.GscSku, SM.LeadTime, SUM(FF.Total_Fcst) as Total_Fcst, CONVERT(varchar, DATE, 1) as Lead_Dates
    FROM GSC.SKU_Master as SM 
    JOIN GSC.Fact_Forecast as FF
    ON SM.GscSku = FF.GscSku
    WHERE SM.GscSku = 'WN80201ONE' and Date BETWEEN '05/04/20' and '08/24/20'
    GROUP BY SM.LeadTime, SM.GscSku, Date
```

**

So far i got the result i want:

[image]

now the next step I want is to get the accumlative sum on the date range. the expected result I want is this

[image]

Comment: How come LeadTime_Date = 8/26/2020 ?

Comment: it's actually suppose to be 08/24/2020 - thanks for the catch

Comment: Simply use the aggregate MAX on your Date (nice name, btw) column and remove that column from your group by clause.

Comment: And let's practice "best practices" to make it a habit. Reference every column with the appropriate alias, not just some of them. And does the order of rows in your resultset matter? Usually it does - the query must include an order by clause to guarantee it. And no we NEVER use 2 digit year literals! And we should always use a literal format that is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sqlserver. But, this should hopefully work:

```
    SELECT GscSku, LeadTime, SUM(Total_Fcst) as TTL_Fcst, MAX(Lead_Dates) as LeadTime_Date FROM
    (
        SELECT SM.GscSku as GscSku, SM.LeadTime as LeadTime, SUM(FF.Total_Fcst) as Total_Fcst,
        CONVERT(varchar, DATE, 1) as Lead_Dates
            FROM GSC.SKU_Master as SM 
            JOIN GSC.Fact_Forecast as FF
            ON SM.GscSku = FF.GscSku
            WHERE SM.GscSku = 'WN80201ONE' and Date BETWEEN '05/04/20' and '08/24/20'
            GROUP BY SM.LeadTime, SM.GscSku, Date
    );
```

Comment: Totally forgot about the MAX aggregation function, thanks for that but now it's giving me Column 'SM.GscSku' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks actually i figured it out. thanks for the help